# Error installing sdl2 on lubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, lubuntu

Trying to install the [love game engine](https://launchpad.net/~bartbes/+archive/love-stable) but I seem to be unable to install the SDL2. I get an error about its dependencies. I googled around and tried to purge but it didn't work. How can I fix/properly install sdl2?

I tried the -f, but didn't work

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
 libsdl2.0debian
The following NEW packages will be installed:
 libsdl2.0debian
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
9 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/346 kB of archives.
After this operation, 954 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 302833 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libsdl2.0debian:amd64 (from .../libsdl2.0debian_2.0-20130310-2~quantal1_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libsdl2.0debian_2.0-20130310-2~quantal1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.0.0', which is also in package libsdl2-2.0-0:amd64 2.0.0+dfsg1-quantal1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libsdl2.0debian_2.0-20130310-2~quantal1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (
```

---

The output for liblove:

```
$ sudo apt-get install liblove
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
  The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   liblove : Depends: libluajit-5.1-2 but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libphysfs1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libsdl2 (>= 2.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libphysfs-1.0-0
   libsdl2-image1.2 : Depends: libsdl2.0debian but it is not going to be installed
   libsdl2-mixer1.2 : Depends: libsdl2.0debian but it is not going to be installed
   libsdl2.0-dev : Depends: libsdl2.0debian (= 2.0-20130310-2~quantal1) but it is not going to be installed
   E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

---

[edit] @Avinash

```
sudo dpkg -r libsdl2-2.0-0
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove libsdl2-2.0-0:amd64, only the config
files of which are on the system; use --purge to remove them too
```

---

[edit2]

when I try to install the dependencies for liblove/love this is the output

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
 autotools-dev is already the newest version.
 autotools-dev set to manually installed.
 build-essential is already the newest version.
 libflac-dev is already the newest version.
 libogg-dev is already the newest version.
 libvorbis-dev is already the newest version.
 pkg-config is already the newest version.
 libdevil-dev is already the newest version.
 libopenal-dev is already the newest version.
 libfreetype6-dev is already the newest version.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
 requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
 distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
 or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsdl2-dev : Depends: libsdl2 (= 2.0.1ppa1quantal1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: try aptitude instead of apt-get, it will usually give you some sort of choice on how to resolve the dependency.

Comment: also you can see if those versions of your dependencies have been packaged for ubuntu at http://packages.ubuntu.com/ and download and install them directly from there.  If not you can see if they exist in a PPA https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas

Answer (score 0):

First remove `libsdl2-2.0-0` package by running,

```
sudo dpkg -r libsdl2-2.0-0
```

Then try,

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Now try to install `liblove` package using aptitude,

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude install liblove
```

Comment: Added output to main post

Comment: try `sudo apt-get purge libsdl2-2.0-0` or `sudo dpkg -P libsdl2-2.0-0`

Comment: it says it says it's removed; however, when I try to install libsdl2 or liblove in aptitude it says "keep the following [...]" which are not installed. Prompts [y/n/q] if I press n it says the same thing. If I hit Y then nothing changes. If I try to install from synaptic, it says it's (libsdl2) is broken

Comment: after it's removed try `sudo apt-get -f install`,if there any error occurs then post it's output to pastebin.com and then provide the link here.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Pir8A7kG

Comment: i think all works.

Comment: it's not installing libsdl2 nor liblove though

Comment: what was the output of `sudo apt-get install libsdl2-2.0-0`?